# Run process with admin credentials

Tags: c#

i have been working on this for a while now and its driving me crazy, after a lot of searching and reading still no solution.
I'm trying to start a process with "Elevated" (domain admin) rights.

this is my code:

```
public class StartProcess
{
    private ProcessStartInfo info;

    private SecureString ConvertPassword(string _password)
    {
        SecureString password = new SecureString();

        for (int i = 0; i < _password.Length; i++)
        {
            password.AppendChar(_password[i]);
        }

        return password;
    }

    public void Start(string path, string fileName)
    {
        info = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName);

        info.Domain = "setours";
        info.UserName = "administrator";
        info.Password = ConvertPassword("ServerTotal_2013");

        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.WorkingDirectory = path;

        try
        {
            Process.Start(info);
        }
        catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Just for debuggin purpuses
            MessageBox.Show(path + fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling the function based on a button click event in my main class:

```
private StartProcess startProcess = new StartProcess();

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;

        switch (button.Content.ToString())
        {
            case "Contable":
                startProcess.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\StarSoft GE", "\\Contabilidad.exe");
                break;
            case "Planilla":

                break;
            case "Caja y banco":

                break;
            case "Cuentas por pagar":

                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Unknown process");
                break;
        }
    }
```

I have also tried this with user impersonation but that also doesn't seem to work.
I have been strugling with 2 errors:

1. Cannot find the path specified
2. Access denied

Other posts are stating that if you use the `user` and `password` parameters of the `ProcessInfo` you need to set the `UseShellExecute` to `false`.
And if you have set it to `false`, the `workingDirectory` is not being used anymore.

Does anyone have any sugestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void RunElevated(string fileName)
{
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processInfo.Verb = "runas";
    processInfo.FileName = fileName;
    try
    {
        Process.Start(processInfo);
    }
    catch (Win32Exception)
    {
        //Do nothing. Probably the user canceled the UAC window
    }
}
```

Comment: That will work, but only under Win 7 or higher, UAC is not disabled  and the user is not loged in with local admin permissions. If he has local admin rights he will not be prompted for credentials.

Comment: Won't that pop up UAC to ask for credentials ?